# How to validate redirect link?

Tags: c#, redirect, selenium-webdriver

I using Selenium Webdriver for testing mobile version site.When i use GoToUrl function, it open the main page of site, and then automaticaly redirect to new window by javascript with request to launch external application(iTunes). Link is not visible in address bar.
How i can switch to new window and get redirect link by webdriver in c#? Please help.

Comment: Thanks, i've solved my problem. I used driver.WindowHandles and get  a Handle of new window and then driver.Url

Comment: is it driver.url? or driver.getCurrentUrl()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the full URL then compare...

`string url = driver.Url; // should return active url`